# How can a spatial reference system be corrupt per OSR while valid per QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr

I have this coordinate reference system defenition:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS["NAVD_1988_Foot_US",VDATUM["North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988"],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]
```

I run this test using osr python module to check if projection definition is valid.

```
import osr
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromESRI(['GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS["NAVD_1988_Foot_US",VDATUM["North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988"],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]'])
srs.Validate()
```

This outputs 5, which is OGRError for corrupt data.

When I use this same string to validate crs definition in QGIS it is saying the proj definition is valid.
[image]
How can a spatial reference system be corrupt per OSR while valid per QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

As per OSR, the validation is not comprehensive, check below :

```
public int Validate​()
```

Validate SRS tokens.
This method attempts to verify that the spatial reference system is well formed, and consists of known tokens. **The validation is not comprehensive.**

Returns:
0 on success. Otherwise throws a RuntimeException() (or an error code if DontUseExceptions() has been called).

You can add below code to get the EPSG code to double check:

```
import osr
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromESRI(['GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS["NAVD_1988_Foot_US",VDATUM["North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988"],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]'])

srs.AutoIdentifyEPSG()
code = srs.GetAuthorityCode(None)
```

**Reference:**
https://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/osr/SpatialReference.html#Validate--

Comment: I ran your additional code. I get EPSG code 4269, the definition of which is not exactly same as the one I gave as input and when I validate after doing 'srs.AutoIdentifyEPSG()', I still get OGRError. 
How can I make sure that the original definition I gave to it is valid. Is there any other library to use here? What library does QGIS use at the background?

Comment: It may be a valid coordinates in QGIS but EPSG is same as OSR, as 4629 is similar to the coordinates you defined here https://epsg.io/4269